# Month View in Userform - Close automatically

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to click in a certain cell and for the Userform with the Monthview to appear , then once I have selected a date and it is inserted into the cell, i want the userform to close automatically

*This code is in Work Sheet*

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("l14"), target) Is Nothing Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

*This code is in the UserForm - MonthView1*

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    ActiveCell.Value = DateClicked
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be Grateful

Answer (score 4):

[`UserForm1.Show` is toxic](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/); you're essentially storing state in global scope, and that will inevitably cause issues down the line. Make a *new instance* of the form instead:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("l14"), target) Is Nothing Then
    With New UserForm1
        .Show
    End With
End If
```

Now, a form/dialog exists to *collect user input*, not to consume that input and change cell values. What happens to that input should be up to the code that's using that form, not up to the form itself. Expose the selected `Date` value with a property.

The user can do 2 things: either they select a date and you have a `SelectedDate`, or they clicked that [X] button and dismissed the form: You need to be able to tell what the user did. Handle `QueryClose` for that, and expose an `IsCancelled` property.

Selecting a date, or cancelling out, should **hide** the form, not destroy it.

```
Option Explicit
Private selectedValue As Date
Private cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Public Property Get SelectedDate() As Date
    SelectedDate = selectedValue
End Property

Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    selectedValue = DateClicked
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        cancelled = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

And now you have a date picker form that you can reuse whenever you need it, because it doesn't know or care about what happens to the value that was selected:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("l14"), target) Is Nothing Then
    With New UserForm1 ' todo: rename form to "DatePickerDialog" or something
        .Show
        If Not .IsCancelled Then
            target.Value = .SelectedDate
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Thank Youthis seams like a lot of code , just to open up a calendar , chose a date and for it too close

Comment: @Bod213 try writing it in C, you'll redefine what "lot of code" stands for ;-)

Comment: @Bod213 to be fair it's not "just to open up a calendar, chose a date and for it to close" - for that you can just stick `Me.Hide` in your current code, where the other answer has `Unload Me`. Then you'll have to deal with buggy code that you can't reuse, so when you need a date picker that needs to do something else than assign `ActiveCell.Value`, you either need a new form, or start spaghettifying your form's code-behind. This "lots of code" solution doesn't have a form running the show; the form only serves 1 purpose: *collecting user input*... as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `unload me` in that sub:

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    ActiveCell.Value = DateClicked
    Unload me
End Sub
```